# Select with match and order by date and then relevance?

Tags: mysql, sql

Im using the below to select from 3 columns and it works as it should but when I try to add date to order by then I can´t get it right. Its a mysql database.

```
    SELECT *,
          MATCH(artikel) AGAINST ("&soktexten&" IN BOOLEAN MODE)* 10 as rel1,
          MATCH(ingress) AGAINST ("&soktexten&" IN BOOLEAN MODE) as rel2,
          MATCH(texten) AGAINST ("&soktexten&" IN BOOLEAN MODE) as rel3
 FROM produkt
 WHERE MATCH (artikel, ingress, texten) AGAINST ("&soktexten&" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
 ORDER BY (rel1)+(rel2)+(rel3) DESC LIMIT 25;
```

I have 3 rows where the "artikel" has the following text and then the date .

```
Row 1 - "Träbord" - "2019-01-01"
Row 2 - "Träbord aaa" - "2019-01-02"
Row 3 - "Träbord bbb" - "2019-01-03"
```

I want it to search for the latest date where the matching word is in "artikel".

So if I search for "Träbord bbb" or "Träbord aaa" it is showing them on top of the list as they should, but if I search for only "Träbord" it is showing "Träbord" as the first one in the list and I want it to search for the latest date first, then the matching word.

So how do I change `ORDER BY (rel1)+(rel2)+(rel3) DESC LIMIT 25` so it order by date first and then by the matching word?

I have tested with several variants of `ORDER BY (rel1)+(rel2)+(rel3), date DESC LIMIT 25` etc but I can´t get it right.
Any input really appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
ORDER BY (rel1 + rel2 + rel3) > 0 DESC,  -- put matches first
         date DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, yes almost. If I search for only "Träbord" then it displays the rows right, it selects by date. But if I search for "Träbord aaa" then it still selects the latest date on top and thats - "Träbord bbb".

Comment: @ClaesGustavsson . . . Well, you have to choose between a partial match and the date.  It is not clear what you want.

Comment: Ok, I want to show the latest date first in my list, and if "artikel" has the word "Träbord" in it then show all posts where we find "Träbord". But if I search for "Träbord aaa" then that is a match for both words so even if the date is older it should come first in the list.